# MUI Datagrid column typescript error when setting a column type

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, datagrid, mui-datatable

I am using DataGrid Pro to build a table.

```
const columns: GridColDef[] = [
  {
    field: 'name',
    headerName: tableColumns.name,
    minWidth: 100,
    resizable: true,
    flex: 1,
  },
  {
    field: 'x',
    headerName: x,
    resizable: false,
    flex: 1,
  },
  {
    field: 'y',
    headerName: y,
    minWidth: 220,
    resizable: false,
    flex: 1,
    renderCell: ({ row }: RenderCellType) => row?.y || 'N/A',
  },
  {
    field: 'z',
    headerName: z,
    minWidth: 75,
    resizable: false,
    flex: 1,
    renderCell: ({ row }: RenderCellType) => <Z vehicle={row} />,
  },
]

  <DataTable // <- i renamed it due to styling needs
    onRowSelect={(abc) => someFunction(abc)}
    selectionModel={filteredIds}
    columns={columns}
    loading={loading}
    rows={filteredRows}
  />
```

and the component is throwing some TS errors
[image]

So, I tried to change the column type to GridColumns instead, but the error persisted.

This is my component types for now

```
type DataTableProps<R extends Row[]> = {
  columns: GridColDef[]
  rows: R
  loading: boolean
  selectionModel: string[]
  onRowSelect: (row: R) => unknown
}
```

I also tried to create a generic type, but didnt work either.

```
type DataTableProps<C extends GridColDef[], R extends Row[]> = {
  columns: C
  ...etc
```

So I am not sure how to fix this. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

I'll provide a working example I have, hopefully this can help you work backwards to a working solution.

```
import { DataGrid } from '@mui/x-data-grid';
import type { FunctionComponent } from 'react';
import type { GridColDef, GridValueGetterParams } from '@mui/x-data-grid';
import { format } from 'date-fns';

type RecordWithCategory = {
  id: number;
  uuid: string;
  date: Date;
  value: number;
  category: {
    title: string;
  }
};

const columns: GridColDef<RecordWithCategory>[] = [
  {
    field: 'date',
    headerName: 'Date',
    valueGetter: ({ row }: GridValueGetterParams<string, RecordWithCategory>) => {
      const { date } = row;
      return format(date, 'yyyy-MM-dd');
    },
  },
  {
    field: 'value',
    headerName: 'Value',
    type: 'number',
  },
  {
    field: 'category',
    headerName: 'Category',
    valueGetter: ({ row }: GridValueGetterParams<string, RecordWithCategory>) => row.category.title,
    },
];

type GraphViewProps = {
    records: RecordWithCategory[];
};

const TableView: FunctionComponent<GraphViewProps> = ({ records }) => {
    return (<DataGrid rows={records} columns={columns} pageSize={25} rowsPerPageOptions={[5]} />);
};
```

Answer (score -3):

Should the type for `columns` be `GridColumns`?

Comment: What help do you need with that question?